# How to read .rpt files and load data to database

Tags: java

I need to read .rpt files and load the data into MySQL or Oracle using Java.
Can anyone help in this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, .rpt files are used by [BIRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIRT_Project).
Are the .rpt (report) files processed in any way or do you just have to write them into a database?
In case of the latter, the necessary steps are:

- Create a list of all .rpt files
- For each of the files:

  - Read the file into a String
  - CREATE a SQL INSERT statement and execute it against your database
- [Profit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-eak9Jz3_k).

  I will expand this answer if you clarify your requirements.

Comment: My .rpt file contains plain data along with column names. i dont think they are processed in any ways

Comment: Does that mean you are interested in the contents of each file? Or do you only need to write the file's contents (as a string) to a field in your database? And do you have an existing database scheme? If so, write it into your original question.

Comment: i dont have db schema. But i need to create the schema and write data into the fields
yes i m interested in the contents of each file.

Comment: Does each .rpt file contain different information about the columns you mentioned? Does the amount of columns change across the .rpt files (affects the database scheme)? And do you need information about each column? That would require parsing each .rpt file, which is loads of more work. You would need a xml parser with xpath support (.rpt files are xml-based afaik).

Comment: at present i have to make it only for 1 rpt file 
and i need to restore data of all the columns of tht rpt file into 1 table